# Filter PivotTable from a list of values - VBA Code

Tags: pivot-table

I am trying to create VBA code that will select a list of values from a range and then take those values and display those in a pivottable. More simply the pivottable will look within the set range and then display only those values. All the values in my list will be for a single filter, that is they will all be model numbers for a product. I am only trying to manipulate a single filter not multiple filters.

Let me know thoughts.

Comment: Hey, if you could share how far you got and what is a sticking point it will be easier to help with your solution.

Comment: Here is the code. I am able to create it for a single value but I need to be able to select multiple values.Sub Macro6()
'
'Dim dt As String
dt = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H5").Value
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem


Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ASIN")
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
   If pi.Name = dt Then
        pi.Visible = True
    Else
        pi.Visible = False
    End If
    Next
    
End Sub